# Javascript nested array and setting the variable

Tags: javascript

```
for (i = 0; i < length1; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < length2; j++) {
    for (k = j; k < length2; k++) {}
  }
}
```

I just wondered... in the last loop where I initialize `k` to be equal to `j`, would it cause problems for me later on?

I'm assuming every time `j` increments by 1, `k` is set to the new value of `j` and then increments up to `length2`

Comment: You should try it out and step through the loops using your browser's debugger.

Comment: What kind of problems do you think you may have with this…?

Comment: @deceze Sorry but your close vote doesn't justify here

Comment: Better to use `var` or `let` to declare the variables, but without more information it seems ok.

Comment: To easily see what's going on just add .write() calls to dump out the value of each variable inside of k's for-loop.  I think it'll do as you hope but you'll see for yourself. As long as length1 and length2 are relatively small, like 5 or 10 it won't be hard to take in and understand.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Is it not? It's an open ended question, and the two already existing answers are already veering off into opposite directions…

Comment: I have a connect 4 game where I am trying to determine winning positions. I've been stuck on this for about 2 weeks lol. I just have unpredictable behaviour in my code. When I posted the entire code on stackoverflow, no one answered my question

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that for each iteration of the j-for-loop, the innermost loop will begin at J's current value and iterate up to length2-1.  If this is what you want, shouldn't be a problem.